# Linq with nullable variable: how perform comparision

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

in asp mvc i have an entity framework model generated from a database. I have the following generated entity class:

```
public partial class person
{
    ...
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> data { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now in my controller i want compare the "data" variable to check if the year is the current year: how can i do this in linq with nullable datetime?

I have tried:

```
 List<person> listOfPeople = (from p in db.person
                              where p.data.Value.Year = currentYear
                              select p).ToList();
```

But i get the following errors:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'
Property or indexer 'System.DateTime.Year' cannot be assigned to --
```

Comment: You're using an assignment operator, not an equality operator.

Comment: Try `where p.data.Value.Year == currentYear`. Notice the double `==`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the following:

```
 where p.data.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year;
```

As for the error you get:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

In the where you should have an expression that could be evaluated to either true/false.

This

```
List<person> listOfPeople = (from p in db.person
                             where p.data.Value.Year ==  DateTime.Now.Year
                             select p).ToList();
```

At the first step of compilation it would be converted to the following:

```
List<person> listOfPeople = db.person.Where(p=>p.data.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
                                     .ToList();
```

The `Where` takes as argument a predicate. The predicate's signature is either this:

```
Func<TSource, bool>
```

or this:

```
Func<TSource, int, bool>
```

The `Where` method is overloaded. As you notice the return type of this is a `bool`.

This expression `p.data.Value.Year = currentYear` is an assignment and it cannot be converted to a predicate like the above mentioned.

**Update**

As a better design, I would suggest you declare you class like below:

```
public partial class person
{
    ...
    // Use a meaningful name for your properties, variables, methods etc.
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Furthermore, **since the** `Date` **is a nullable** `DateTime`, you have to check first if it already has a value.

That being said, you should use the following query:

```
List<person> listOfPeople = (from p in db.person
                             where p.Date.HasValue &&
                                   p.Date.Value.Year ==  DateTime.Now.Year
                             select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, however, OP should probably add a null check on `p.data`, else some fun null reference exceptions are in his future.

Comment: @Tommy thank for your comment. I updated correspondingly my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the double `==` for value comparison. Also you need to add an nullcheck (`HasValue`) to prevent NullReferenceExceptions when accessing the `.Year` property of a null DateTime.

```
 List<person> listOfPeople = (from p in db.person
                              where p.data.HasValue 
                                && p.data.Value.Year == currentYear
                              select p).ToList();
```